# Null pointer exception when trying to stop repeating J internal form

Tags: java, netbeans, nullpointerexception

I wanted to stop repeating J internal form by clicking the label in Home J Frame. 
And I'm trying to add "<<" to the label after I load the form. Now, I'm getting null pointer exception when I'm trying to load the second J internal form.
This is my method to load J internal form:

```
public void lordForm(JInternalFrame frame) { 
        jDesktopPane1.add(frame);
        frame.setVisible(true);
    }


    public void load(String ss, JInternalFrame in, JLabel jl) {

        JInternalFrame[] j = jDesktopPane1.getAllFrames();
        boolean b = false;

       for (JInternalFrame jI : j) {
            if (jI.getName().equals(ss)) {
                b = true;
                break;
            } 
        } 
        if (!b) {
            LF(in);
            jl.setText(ss + " >>"); 
            jl.setEnabled(false);

        } else { 
          in.moveToFront();
        }
    }
```

I'm Using **moveToFront()** method to move the selected J internal form.

These are the cords to label mouse releasing events:

```
private void lblinvoiceMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) <br/> {                                         
load("Invoice", new Invoice(), lblinvoice);

    }   
  private void lblReservationMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){                                             
   load("Reservation", new Reservation(), lblReservation);

    }
```

Stack trace is given below.

```
Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.NullPointerException at 
viewer.MainFrame.load(MainFrame.java:39) at 
viewer.MainFrame.lblinvoiceMouseReleased(MainFrame.java:186) at 
viewer.MainFrame.access$000(MainFrame.java:18) at 
viewer.MainFrame$1.mouseReleased(MainFrame.java:82)
```

And `viewer.MainFrame.load(MainFrame.java:39)` is `if (jI.getName().equals(ss)) {` at `viewer.MainFrame.lblinvoiceMouseReleased(MainFrame.java:186)` is `load("Invoice", new Invoice(), lblinvoice);`

Comment: Which line are you getting a null pointer on?

Comment: if I click lblReservation as the second interface null pointer exception will getting from that line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the NPE might be in this block:

```
for (JInternalFrame jI : j) { // The first time j length == 0, so the loop is not executed
    if (jI.getName().equals(ss)) { // In this line, if jI.getName() == null, you'll get NPE
        b = true;
        break;
    } 
 }
```

Are you sure you're setting the name of the `JInternalFrame` objects when you create them? This would explain why the first time you don't get NPE but the second time you do. If not so, please post the NPE's stack trace.

**Update**: based on stack trace recently added, the problem is the line I pointed above. So, you should make following changes to avoid NPE:

```
private void lblinvoiceMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt) {
    String name = "Invoice";
    Invoice invoice = new Invoice();
    invoice.setName(name); 
    load(name, invoice, lblinvoice);
}

private void lblReservationMouseReleased(java.awt.event.MouseEvent evt){
    String name = "Reservation";
    Reservation reservation = new Reservation();
    reservation.setName(name);
    load(name, reservation, lblReservation);

}
```

Comment: Please edit your question and add this stack trace there not in this comment section. Also please check which line is `viewer.MainFrame.load(MainFrame.java:39)`in your code (I suspect it is `if (jI.getName().equals(ss))`).

Comment: Ok. Now I'm not having the null pointer exception. But I think my in.moveToFront(); method is not working. Can you give me any other method. Or cord to move front the J internal form when I'm having lots of J internal forms on my J panel form? When I'm clicking the same label to load. As an example I loaded Invoice > Reservation > Stock on the J panel. And I want to bring Invoice as the fronted J internal form.

Comment: Actually I put tick on iconifiable button, So I can can minimize other J internal forms and bring one I needed to front. If you have some thing else using methods and cording please let know.

Comment: I'm sorry I can't help you because I have never used JInternalFrame :( I think it should be posted in a new question since is a completely different topic. If my answer (related to NPE) did work for you, please mark it as accepted so people looking for a similar problem can identify this as useful.